# IPSEC tool Racoon Crashes and can't restart it

Tags: security, macos, vpn, ipsec

I'm using a PowerBook Pro running Mac OSX 10.6.6 (Snow Leopard). I have been connecting to a client server using the built in VPN connector for months. Yesterday my connection wouldn't connect and was timing out.  I checked with other remote developers and they had the same issue.  The resolved it by killing the "racoon" process.  I did the same and VPN connected.

I googled Racon to discover that it is an IPsec tool (http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net/)

This morning I had the same issue. I decided to first try to flush the info by using the racoonctl app to run:
`sudo racoonctl flush-sa ipsec`

That didn;t work, so I decided to just kill the process.  Sadly, I do not have a racoon process running now.  So I rebooted.  Still not process.  I rebooted again and ran fsck.  Still nothing.

I looked in the logs and it seems that racoon is crashing every 10 seconds (see below).

Anybody have any ideas on what I need to do to get this back up and running? This has seemed to happen out of the blue and it is eating up my time seriously at this point.

### System Error:

```
__TEXT [0x100000000 - 0x10008f000) __eh_frame [0x1000821e8 - 0x10008eff8) /usr/sbin/racoon
Mar  9 12:35:11 pmolaro com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.racoon[2458]): Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
Mar  9 12:35:11 pmolaro com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.racoon): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
Mar  9 12:35:11 pmolaro com.apple.ReportCrash.Root[2454]: 2011-03-09 12:35:11.638 ReportCrash[2454:301b] Saved crash report for racoon[2458] version ??? (???) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/racoon_2011-03-09-123511_localhost.crash
```

---

### Crash Report:

```
Process:         racoon [720]
Path:            /usr/sbin/racoon
Identifier:      racoon
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-09 10:42:19.831 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000d, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc01723 dyld::setNewProgramVars(ProgramVars const&) + 64
1   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc0d8d9 ImageLoaderMachO::setupLazyPointerHandler(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 297
2   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc18a19 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::doBind(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool) + 57
3   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc0b5a2 ImageLoader::recursiveBind(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool) + 122
4   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc0c81b ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 171
5   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc04d48 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 118
6   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc068d6 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**) + 2822
7   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc016d2 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long) + 799
8   dyld                            0x00007fff5fc01052 _dyld_start + 42

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x00000001000003c8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0921b00000000100
  rdi: 0x000000010008fac0  rsi: 0x00007fff5fc277c1  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfdac0  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfdac0
   r8: 0x00007fff5fc444b0   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x00007fff893d5d3f  r11: 0x00007fff5fc0d6aa
  r12: 0x00000001000002e0  r13: 0x0000000000000002  r14: 0x0000000100000000  r15: 0x00007fff5fc43be8
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01723  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000010008f048

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x10008eff7 +racoon ??? (???)  /usr/sbin/racoon
       0x1000a0000 -        0x1000a5fef  libipsec.A.dylib 300.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libipsec.A.dylib
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???)  /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80008000 -     0x7fff8000dfff  libpam.2.dylib 3.0.0 (compatibility 3.0.0)  /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff8125e000 -     0x7fff8141ffff  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.1 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff81528000 -     0x7fff817aefff  com.apple.security 6.1.1 (37594)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff817d8000 -     0x7fff81815fff  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1)  /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
    0x7fff81c85000 -     0x7fff81c89ff7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff81fcf000 -     0x7fff81fefff7  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.9)  /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
    0x7fff8259a000 -     0x7fff82617fef  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0)  /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff82618000 -     0x7fff827d6fff  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff82831000 -     0x7fff82952fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8)  /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff829cf000 -     0x7fff82a85fff  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff82cca000 -     0x7fff82cebfff  libresolv.9.dylib 41.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff84b80000 -     0x7fff84b91ff7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0)  /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff84c47000 -     0x7fff84c59fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0)  /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff85fb4000 -     0x7fff86000fff  libauto.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff862a8000 -     0x7fff862e2fff  libssl.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8)  /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff86ac2000 -     0x7fff86ac3ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1)  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8735e000 -     0x7fff87374fef  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff87375000 -     0x7fff8746dff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0)  /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff87593000 -     0x7fff875d4fff  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.5 (1.10.2)  /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff87ae1000 -     0x7fff87c58fe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.4 (550.42)  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff87e02000 -     0x7fff87ebbfff  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0)  /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff883a0000 -     0x7fff8844ffff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.10 (6.5.10)  /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fffffe00000 -     0x7fffffe01fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???)  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally resolved my own issue.  I used TimeMachine to replace the /usr/sbin/racoon and /usr/sbin/racoonctl files and rebooted my system. Now VPN works as expected.  I am guessing that one of those files (probably racoon) was corrupted somehow.

On a side note, I did call Apple to get some help. I was willing to pay the support fee to get this issue resolved.  After they read my information on this page I was informed that this issue was "beyond their technical training." I asked if I could speak to a higher level tech who would know something about the underpinnings of the OS and was told that wasn't an option. The tech finally recommended that I spend an hour and re-install my OS to fix the issue.  Never once suggested TimeMachine either.

Moral of that story:  Unless you need to know how to connect your printer or surf the web in an iPad, you probably don;t want to waste your time or money with Apple support.  Sorry Apple, in this you have failed me!  :(

Comment: Thanks for the good question and answer! Please go ahead and select your own answer as the one for this question to give yourself some credit!